# Download xml file after login website automation

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The login website https://company.okta.com/login/default is sso authentication, once this is successful, it takes me to other page https://auth.p0rtal.com/login/callback then after few seconds it takes to the page https://clock.company.com/sitemap.xml.

i want to download the sitemap.xml from here, i.e right click on the page, click on save as and get the file.

below code works sucessfully to authenticate, I am new to python and selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import yaml

conf = yaml.load(open('loginDetails.yml'))
myEmail = conf['user']['email']
myPassword = conf['user']['password']

driver = webdriver.Chrome('//Users/user.id/Desktop/website_login/chromedriver') 

def login(url,usernameId, username, passwordId, password, submit_buttonId):
   driver.get(url)
   driver.find_element_by_id(usernameId).send_keys(username)
   driver.find_element_by_id(passwordId).send_keys(password)
   driver.find_element_by_id(submit_buttonId).click()
login("https://company.okta.com/login/default", "okta-signin-username", myEmail, "okta-signin-password", myPassword, "okta-signin-submit")
```

After this how do i automate the click and save as once authentication is success.

pyautogui?

Comment: You could write the content to a file with `driver.page_source`